# Apache Flink: NullPointerException in DataSet API Outer Join

Tags: java, sql, dataset, apache-flink

I'm trying to implement the following simple Query in Flink's Dataset API.

```
select 
    t1_value1 
from  
    table1 
where  
    t1_suppkey not in ( 
        select  
            t2_suppkey
        from  
            table2
     )
```

So my idea was to perform a Left Outer Join (table1.leftOuterJoin(table2)...) and then delete all the rows where I get a value for t1_suppkey and t2_suppkey.

So I tried it like this:

```
     output = table1
    .leftOuterJoin(table2).where("t1_suppkey").equalTo("t2_suppkey")
    .with((Table1 t1, Table2 t2) -> new Tuple2<>(t1.ps_suppkey, t2.s_suppkey))
    .returns(new TypeHint <Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {});
```

However if I do it like this it always fails with "java.lang.NullPointerException" and I'm not sure why. If I use a normal Join instead of a Left Outer Join the code works, but that's not what I want.

Do I need to implement a Left Join differently or is there a more simple way to rewrite the "not in" statement in the Dataset API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer join of the DataSet API calls the `JoinFunction` also for outer records that don't find a joining record on the inner side. In this case, [the `JoinFunction.join()` method is called with `null`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#outerjoin-with-join-function).

Since you are using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, the second argument `Table2 t2` can be `null`. The `NullPointerException` is caused by `t2.s_suppkey`. You need to check for `t2 == null` and only access `t2` if it is not null.

You can also implement the NOT IN join with a [`FlatJoinFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#outerjoin-with-flat-join-function) that has a `Collector` argument and only emit `t1` if `t2 == null`.

Another option is to use Flink's batch [SQL support](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/sql.html) which supports the query in your example.

Comment: Thanks, solved it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074758/8180276) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = table1
.leftOuterJoin(table2)
.where("t1_suppkey").equalTo("t2_suppkey") 
.with((Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Collector<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> c) -> { 
if(t2 == null) {
    c.collect(new Tuple2<>(t1.t1_suppkey, t1.t1_value1)); 
} 
else { 
    //Do nothing. 
}})
```